# Unable to Access SBS 2011 Backup Drive

Tags: backup, windows-sbs-2011

I have a client running an SBS 2011 server that is configured to make backups to an external hard drive via the built in server backup utility. I am unable to access this drive - It shows up in disk management but there is no drive letter assigned. When I assign a drive letter, the drive shows up but I get an access denied error when attempting to open.

Is this normal behavior for an SBS backup drive?

Comment: AFAIK, it is. Windows "reserves" the drive for backups and does not assign a drive letter to it, presumably to protect you from inadvertently accessing the drive in Windows Explorer and mucking with the backed up data directly. You should probably NOT be assigning a drive letter or otherwise be "mucking" around with the drive. The client has presumably attached the drive for the sole purpose of Windows Server Backup backups, so it's best to leave it alone and let Windows Server Backup manage the drive.

Comment: Okay, I was just making sure that it was in fact Windows limiting access to the drive and not some other issue with the drive itself. Is there a way to verify the backups are taking place?

Comment: You should be able to run the Windows Server Backup management console to check the status of the backups.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is. Windows "reserves" the drive for backups and does not assign a drive letter to it, presumably to protect you from inadvertently accessing the drive in Windows Explorer and mucking with the backed up data directly. You should probably NOT be assigning a drive letter or otherwise be "mucking" around with the drive. The client has presumably attached the drive for the sole purpose of Windows Server Backup backups, so it's best to leave it alone and let Windows Server Backup manage the drive.

You should be able to run the Windows Server Backup management console to check the status of the backups.

**EDIT:**

As an aside, I captured this image from Windows Server Backup, which is what SBS backups use under the covers.

[image]